# How to make the output as another input?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

The case: We have a 1day aggregation window which sum the total value received from Event hub (1, 2, 3 … each minute send a value), we set the output to a blob called 1dayresult. Now we want to get the blob data as another 1week aggregation input, each week we want to get the data from the blob and do calculation, so can we set the 1day result blob as the input for the 1week aggregation? We know we can set the window unit is 7day, but we think it will slow down the performance, because if we make the 1day result blob as the input, we only need 7 values, but if we use the 7day window, we will get more than 7*24*60 values and then do the calculation. We also want to have a month aggregation, but the  The maximum size of the window is 7 days. So how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WITH statement to "chain" multiple subqueries together, where next subquery can be using output of the previous as input. Take a look at this [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835049.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

However, as you noted, sometimes it can be more efficient to persist intermediate output results in blob storage or another Event Hub. You can define same storage location both as input and as output and one subquery can be outputting while another is reading.

The maximum size of windows in Azure Stream Analytics is indeed 7 days. For bigger size  window computations involving bigger amounts of historic data it might be better to use product like Azure Data Factory.